# How to $watch multiple variable change in angular

Tags: angularjs

How to `$scope.$watch` multiple variables in Angular, and trigger callback when one of them has changed.

```
$scope.name = ...
$scope.age = ...
$scope.$watch('???',function(){
    //called when name or age changed
})
```

Comment: There's [a very good blog post by Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2566-Scope-watch-vs-watchCollection-In-AngularJS.htm) on the topic of $watch vs $watchCollection you might find useful.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

---

**UPDATE**

Angular offers now the two scope methods [$watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchGroup) (since 1.3) and [$watchCollection](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchCollection). Those have been mentioned by @blazemonger and @kargold.

---

This should work independent of the types and values:

```
$scope.$watch('[age,name]', function () { ... }, true);
```

You have to set the third parameter to true in this case.

The string concatenation `'age + name'` will fail in a case like this:

```
<button ng-init="age=42;name='foo'" ng-click="age=4;name='2foo'">click</button>
```

Before the user clicks the button the watched value would be `42foo` (`42` + `foo`) and after the click `42foo` (`4` + `2foo`). So the watch function would not be called. So better use an array expression if you cannot ensure, that such a case will not appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jasmine/1.3.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.2/angular-mocks.js"></script>
        <script>

angular.module('demo', []).controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.firstWatchFunctionCounter = 0;
    $scope.secondWatchFunctionCounter = 0;

    $scope.$watch('[age, name]', function () { $scope.firstWatchFunctionCounter++; }, true);
    $scope.$watch('age + name', function () { $scope.secondWatchFunctionCounter++; });
});

describe('Demo module', function () {
    beforeEach(module('demo'));
    describe('MainCtrl', function () {
        it('watch function should increment a counter', inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
            var scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.age = 42;
            scope.name = 'foo';
            var ctrl = $controller('MainCtrl', { '$scope': scope });
            scope.$digest();

            expect(scope.firstWatchFunctionCounter).toBe(1);
            expect(scope.secondWatchFunctionCounter).toBe(1);

            scope.age = 4;
            scope.name = '2foo';
            scope.$digest();

            expect(scope.firstWatchFunctionCounter).toBe(2);
            expect(scope.secondWatchFunctionCounter).toBe(2); // This will fail!
        }));
    });
});


(function () {
    var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
    var htmlReporter = new jasmine.HtmlReporter();
    jasmineEnv.addReporter(htmlReporter);
    jasmineEnv.specFilter = function (spec) {
        return htmlReporter.specFilter(spec);
    };
    var currentWindowOnload = window.onload;
    window.onload = function() {
        if (currentWindowOnload) {
            currentWindowOnload();
        }
        execJasmine();
    };
    function execJasmine() {
        jasmineEnv.execute();
    }
})();

        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2DwCOftQTltWFbEDiDlA?p=preview

PS:

As stated by @reblace in a comment, it is of course possible to access the values:

```
$scope.$watch('[age,name]', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    var newAge  = newValue[0];
    var newName = newValue[1];
    var oldAge  = oldValue[0];
    var oldName = oldValue[1];
}, true);
```

Comment: @Ajax3.14: What exactly is not working? I cannot reproduce that problem. Could it be, that you see the jasmie output "Failing 1 spec"? That would be the expected output, because the test fails (see the comment in the source code of the test).

Comment: This answer helped me, thanks! The beauty of this approach is you can access the newValue/oldValue as elements of the watched array (eg. newValue[0], newValue[1] and oldValue[0], oldValue[1])

Comment: If the variables you want to watch are all simple primitives, then `$watchCollection` might be more appropriate.

Comment: I kept for getting the `true` part. That part is important for it to work! Thanks for this, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 43):

```
$scope.$watch('age + name', function () {
  //called when name or age changed
});
```

Comment: This will work due to JS concatinating them as Strings. Good answer and the correct one btw.

Comment: To anybody finding answer to the same question - my answer is incorrect, this answer is the right one.

Comment: Also be sure in this case not use the `newValue` and `oldValue` arguments that angular passes into the callback because they will be the resulting concatenation and not just the field that was changed.

Comment: I wonder why people say this answer is correct...

Comment: This was the correct answer at the time I wrote it.

Answer (score 8):

Angular 1.3 provides $watchGroup specifically for this purpose:

[https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watchGroup](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchGroup)

This seems to provide the same ultimate result as a standard $watch on an array of expressions.  I like it because it makes the intention clearer in the code.

Answer (score 6):

There is many way to watch multiple values :

```
//angular 1.1.4
$scope.$watchCollection(['foo', 'bar'], function(newValues, oldValues){
    // do what you want here
});
```

or more recent version

```
//angular 1.3
$scope.$watchGroup(['foo', 'bar'], function(newValues, oldValues, scope) {
  //do what you want here
});
```

Read official doc for more informations : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Why is this voted down? What's wrong with this?

Comment: I believe `watchCollection` has to be a string. I'm going to confirm then edit.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that I believe the new and old values are accessed in different ways between these functions.

Comment: Why was the edit not accepted? `watchCollection` takes a string for the first argument, this is incorrect and I'm removing my upvote.

Comment: I ve tested my answer, be sure it works ^^ you can put a string or like that, i prefer this syntax

Answer (score 6):

No one has mentioned the obvious:

```
var myCallback = function() { console.log("name or age changed"); };
$scope.$watch("name", myCallback);
$scope.$watch("age", myCallback);
```

This might mean a little less polling. If you watch both `name + age` (for this) and `name` (elsewhere) then I assume Angular will effectively look at `name` twice to see if it's dirty.

It's arguably more readable to use the callback by name instead of inlining it. Especially if you can give it a better name than in my example.

And you can watch the values in different ways if you need to:

```
$scope.$watch("buyers", myCallback, true);
$scope.$watchCollection("sellers", myCallback);
```

`$watchGroup` is nice if you can use it, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't let you watch the group members as a collection or with object equality.

If you need the old and new values of *both* expressions inside one and the same callback function call, then perhaps some of the other proposed solutions are more convenient.

Comment: it calls callback function even for the first time when my controller is loaded ? can't I stop it to call for the first time when controller is loaded ?