# angularjs: $watch two variables and do something if only one changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a situation in which I want to monitor a specific variable.

```
$scope.$watch('action', function() { /* do something */ }
```

However, I only want to do something if `$scope.id` didn't change (if `$scope.action` changes it is possible that `$scope.id` has changed too.)

The only solution I can think of is

```
$scope.$watch('action', function() { 
    if(idHasChanhed === false){
        /* do something */ 
    }
    idHasChanged = false;
});
$scope.$watch('id', function() { idHasChanged = true }
```

However, I was wondering if angular has a better solution than this, and I don't know if this solution will always work ( is the order in which the $watches are executed random !?)

Answer (score 4):

My solution :

```
$scope.$watch('[action,id]', function() { 
   // called when action or id changed
});
```

Info : The string concatenation `action + id` will fail.

Comment: Hmm, I've implemented it now and I get the following error: `Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!` It gets triggered all the time without the data changing

Comment: Turns out that my question is a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729965/how-to-watch-multiple-variable-change-in-angular) question

Answer (score 0):

```
var action,id;   // variables you need to watch
 $scope.$watch('action + id', function() { 
       // actions
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> **$watchGroup** This function is introduced in Angular1.3. This works the same as $watch() function except that the first parameter is an array of expressions to watch.

Use `$watchGroup`

```
$scope.$watchGroup(['action', 'id'], function(newVal, oldVal) {
    //write your code here
});
```