# How to watch two expressions which have separate listeners in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, watch

I need to watch two expressions such that each expression have a separate listener. so i wrote two $watch() methods. Is it possible to write both in a single watch statement.

Thanks for ur response, I mean to say for each expression it have a separate listener, (i have two expressions and two listeners i.e one listener for one expression and other listener for second expression) so how to achieve it using single watch() method.

Comment: you can also watch as array - `[watched1, watched2]`

Comment: Thanks for ur response, I mean to say for each expression it have a separate listener, (i have two expressions and two listeners i.e one listener for one expression and other listener for second expression) so how to achieve it using single watch() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/JvJQ90tLcpS0x79ZnDvr?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="angularjs-starter">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Controller example Plunker</title>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome Watch</h1>

  <div ng-controller="SpicyCtrl">
    <div>
      <label>First</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="watch1" />
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
      <label>Second</label>
      <input ng-model="watch2" />
    </div>


    <p>First input value{{watch1}}</p>
    <p>Second input value {{watch2}}</p>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.controller('SpicyCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.$watch('[watch1,watch2]',function(a,b,c){

      if((b[0]!==undefined||a[0]!==undefined) && b[0]!==a[0]){
        //functionality for first watchtrigger
        alert('watch1 changed')
      }
      if((b[1]!==undefined||a[1]!==undefined) && b[1]!==a[1]){
         //functionality for second watchtrigger
        alert('watch2 changed')
      }

    })

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$watchGroup`or `$watchCollection`

Create an array of your different expression and you will get the result in single listner :)

[Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope/#$watchGroup)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$scope.$watch('[first,second]', function () { ... }, true);
```

[REFERENCE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729965/how-to-watch-multiple-variable-change-in-angular)