# AngularJs watch for all in ng-init

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I initialize some variables of an AngularJS controller on the server side using `ng-init`

```
/* in my server side View */
<div ng-controller="myController" ng-init="myFoo=@myFoo;myBar=@myBar">...</div>

/* in the myApp.js */
app.Controller("myController", function(){
  // wait until myFoo and myBar are initialized, 
  // once defined, perform other tasks

  $scope.$watch("myFoo", function(n,o){}); //?
  $scope.$watch("myBar", function(n,o){}); //?

  // other actions, depending on myFoo and myBar
  for(i=0; i<myFoo; i++) { console.log(myBar); }
});
```

I need to ensure that when angularjs reaches the `for` cycle `myFoo` and `myBar` variables are already initialized.

Is there a way of doing it (without using strange things like `magic=1500 $timeout(magic)`)?

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/serhio/pen/yoYxgX)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {


  $scope.myFoo = false;
  $scope.myBar = false;
  
  $scope.$watch("myFoo", function(n,o){
    //$timeout(null,1500);    
    console.log("watch > myFoo from: "+o+" to "+n+"; >"+$scope.myFoo);
  });
  $scope.$watch("myBar", function(n,o){
    //$timeout(null,500);
    console.log("watch > myBar from: "+o+" to "+n+"; >"+$scope.myBar);
  });
  
  console.log("> Main thread: myFoo is: " + $scope.myFoo);
  console.log("> Main thread: myBar is: " + $scope.myBar);
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
  <div  ng-init="myFoo=true;myBar=true"></div>
</div>
```

as we can see from the execution of that code

```
> Main thread: myFoo is: false
> Main thread: myBar is: false
watch > myFoo from: true to true; >true
watch > myBar from: true to true; >true
```

The main thread reaches the variables BEFORE its initialization... 
Bad !

Comment: Why don't you create a service that will return the value from server side?

Comment: is a specific data for that view... should I create services for each view?

Comment: Say, I have a partial view that represents a table, and `myFoo` is `maxRowsToDisplay`

Comment: You can send something to your server side for each view(maybe the name of the partial) and get the desired response back from the same service for each of your different views.

Comment: You can still render your template with a `<script>window.myVar = somevalue;</script>` and use `window.myVar` in your controller. Or even create an angular value `app.value('myVar', window.myVar)` so you can use `myVar` in the controller (you have to use it in requirement of the controller).

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729965/how-to-watch-multiple-variable-change-in-angular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire a function on ng-init.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {


  $scope.myFoo = false;
  $scope.myBar = false;
  
  $scope.$watch("myFoo", function(n,o){
    //$timeout(null,1500);    
    console.log("watch > myFoo from: "+o+" to "+n+"; >"+$scope.myFoo);
  });
  
  $scope.$watch("myBar", function(n,o){
    //$timeout(null,500);
    console.log("watch > myBar from: "+o+" to "+n+"; >"+$scope.myBar);
  });
  
  $scope.load = function(){  
     
        console.log("> Main thread: myFoo is: " + $scope.myFoo);
        console.log("> Main thread: myBar is: " + $scope.myBar);
    
  }
  
 }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
  <div  ng-init="myFoo=true;myBar=true;load()"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even if you remove the initialization, the code will work

Comment: @Vivz you are right. I did that so it will be clear that ng-init is changing the variable value.

Comment: Yeah and do you think this will render the value in view for ng-init ng-init="myFoo=@myFoo;myBar=@myBar"> ?

Comment: it will raise $parse:lexerr Lexer Error,

Comment: Which backend framework is this and is there a way to render the value like this in angularjs without calling a service but directly getting it from the backend code?

Comment: in OP i asked how to be sure that when I execute the `for`, the `myFoo` and `myBar` variables are already initialized (are not undefined or `false`, in your case).

Comment: @Serge from where you want to initialize myFoo, is there any service?
 Question is not clear about that. if you want to fire a function when your view is loaded you can simply call it on ng-init.

Comment: take a look on the updated OP... I initialize the foo and bar in the HTML, in the server side generated view.

Comment: what do you mean by "if"? and "if not", do nothing?

Comment: its just to insure that you have loaded the varible from server side and changed the false value.

Comment: ok, but I don't need just to insure, I need to *wait* till the initialization is finished for both variables, and only then do the things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150417/discussion-between-gaurav-srivastava-and-serge).

Comment: works well. however I consider this to be a "hack" :) thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You could just wait for both variables to come back and then just destroy the listeners:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {


  $scope.myFoo = false;
  $scope.myBar = false;

  var fooListen = $scope.$watch("myFoo", function(n,o){
    console.log("watch > myFoo from: "+o+" to "+n);
    checkInit();
  });
  var barListen = $scope.$watch("myBar", function(n,o){
    console.log("watch > myBar from: "+o+" to "+n);
    checkInit();
  });

  function checkInit(){
    if($scope.myFoo && $scope.myBar){
      console.log("> Main thread: myFoo is: " + $scope.myFoo);
      console.log("> Main thread: myBar is: " + $scope.myBar);
      //remove the watches
      fooListen();
      barListen();
    }

  }
```

In this case each time a variable changes you would listen to the change. When both variables are initialized then you can run what ever code you want. But what about the $watches? you can actually tell them to stop listening. For more info on that you can look here: [AngularJS : Clear $watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957614/angularjs-clear-watch)

And here is a updated pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NvGOQE?editors=1112#anon-login

Comment: your code will not work if the init value will set a "false", not "true" value as it actually does...

Comment: True, but this is only an example, in line with the one you gave me. the logic inside checkInit() could easily be changed to account for this.

Comment: sometimes is hard to undestand if a value is initialized or not.... another example is 0 value... so your check may work or may not...

Comment: probably need additional boolean flags to set

Comment: the remove watches I don't really understand how it works... will they not be triggered after the fooListen() execution?